# Ordenar Recyclerview por fecha

Tags: mysql, recyclerview

Tengo mi RecyclerView que obtiene los datos de mi base de datos MySQL mediante json. El caso es que cuando ejecuto la app y ésta obtiene los datos remotos,quiero que me los ordene por fecha aprovechando el cuadro en el que tengo la fecha.

Necesito que los elementos que tengan una fecha mas reciente estén primero y los de la fecha mas antigua los últimos.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí pongo el código:

Definición de clase Meta:

```
public class Meta {

    private static final String TAG = Meta.class.getSimpleName();
    /*
        Atributos
         */
    private String idMeta;
    private String titulo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String prioridad;
    private String fechaLim;
    private String categoria;

    public Meta(String idMeta,
                String titulo,
                String descripcion,
                String fechaLim,
                String categoria,
                String prioridad) {
        this.idMeta = idMeta;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.prioridad = prioridad;
        this.fechaLim = fechaLim;
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getIdMeta() {
        return idMeta;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getPrioridad() {
        return prioridad;
    }

    public String getFechaLim() {
        return fechaLim;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    /**
     * Compara los atributos de dos metas
     *
     * @param meta Meta externa
     * @return true si son iguales, false si hay cambios
     */
    public boolean compararCon(Meta meta) {
        return this.titulo.compareTo(meta.titulo) == 0 &&
                this.descripcion.compareTo(meta.descripcion) == 0 &&
                this.fechaLim.compareTo(meta.fechaLim) == 0 &&
                this.categoria.compareTo(meta.categoria) == 0 &&
                this.prioridad.compareTo(meta.prioridad) == 0;
    }
}
```

MetaAdapter:

```
/**
 * Adaptador del recycler view
 */
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Meta> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Meta> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.titulo.setText(items.get(i).getTitulo());
        viewHolder.prioridad.setText(items.get(i).getPrioridad());
        viewHolder.fechaLim.setText(items.get(i).getFechaLim());
        viewHolder.categoria.setText(items.get(i).getCategoria());
    }

    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getIdMeta());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView titulo;
        public TextView prioridad;
        public TextView fechaLim;
        public TextView categoria;
        public ItemClickListener listener;

        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            prioridad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prioridad);
            fechaLim = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            categoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoria);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Donde se carga el RecyclerView lista:

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

 ...
 /*
 Adaptador del recycler view
 */
 private MetaAdapter adapter;
 /* 
 Instancia global del recycler view 
 */
 private RecyclerView lista;

 ...


    /**
     * Interpreta los resultados de la respuesta y así
     * realizar las operaciones correspondientes
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json con la respuesta
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Obtener atributo "estado"
            String estado = response.getString("estado");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1": // EXITO
                    // Obtener array "metas" Json
                    JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                    // Parsear con Gson
                    Meta[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta[].class);
                    // Inicializar adaptador
                    adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
                    // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case "2": // FALLIDO
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }


}
```

Lo he ordenado pero necesito ordenarlos por fecha

```
//  Obtener array "metas" Json
            JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
            // Parsear con Gson
            Meta[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta[].class);

            // APLICACIÓN DE ORDEN: 
            // Ordenar el array de metas por idMeta de forma descendente:
            Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator<Meta>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(meta objeto1, meta objeto2) {
                    int result;
                    // Comparamos por idMeta, de forma descendente:
                    result = objeto2.idMeta.compareTo(objeto1.idMeta);
                    /* 
                    // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                    result = objeto2.fechaLim.compareTo(objeto1.fechaLim);
                    */
                    return result;

                }
            });
            // Fin del ordenamiento.

            // Inicializar adaptador
            adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
            // Setear adaptador a la lista
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Creo que es esto a lo que refieres

```
/**
 * Fragmento con formulario para actualizar la meta
*/
public class UpdateFragment extends Fragment {
/*
Etiqueta de depuración
 */
private static final String TAG = UpdateFragment.class.getSimpleName();

/*
Controles
*/
private EditText titulo_input;
private EditText descripcion_input;
private Spinner prioridad_spinner;
private TextView fecha_text;
private Spinner categoria_spinner;

/*
Valor del argumento extra
 */
private String idMeta;

/**
 * Es la meta obtenida como respuesta de la petición HTTP
 */
private Meta metaOriginal;

/**
 * Instancia Gson para el parsing Json
 */
private Gson gson = new Gson();


public UpdateFragment() {
}

/**
 * Crea un nuevo fragmento basado en un argumento
 *
 * @param extra Argumento de entrada
 * @return Nuevo fragmento
 */
public static Fragment createInstance(String extra) {
    UpdateFragment detailFragment = new UpdateFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constantes.EXTRA_ID, extra);
    detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return detailFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflando layout del fragmento
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form, container, false);

    // Obtención de instancias controles
    titulo_input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo_input);
    descripcion_input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_input);
    fecha_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha_ejemplo_text);
    categoria_spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.categoria_spinner);
    prioridad_spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.prioridad_spinner);

    fecha_text.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                    picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                }
            }
    );

    // Obtener valor extra
    idMeta = getArguments().getString(Constantes.EXTRA_ID);

    if (idMeta != null) {
        cargarDatos();
    }

    return v;
}

/**
 * Obtiene los datos desde el servidor
 */
private void cargarDatos() {
    // Añadiendo idMeta como parámetro a la URL
    String newURL = Constantes.GET_BY_ID + "?idMeta=" + idMeta;

    // Consultar el detalle de la meta
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    newURL,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // Procesa la respuesta GET_BY_ID
                            procesarRespuestaGet(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
            )
    );
}

/**
 * Procesa la respuesta de obtención obtenida desde el sevidor     *
 */
private void procesarRespuestaGet(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        String estado = response.getString("estado");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                JSONObject meta = response.getJSONObject("meta");
                // Guardar instancia
                metaOriginal = gson.fromJson(meta.toString(), Meta.class);
                // Setear valores de la meta
                cargarViews(metaOriginal);
                break;

            case "2":
                String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de falla
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Carga los datos iniciales del formulario con los
 * atributos de un objeto {@link Meta}
 *
 * @param meta Instancia
 */
private void cargarViews(Meta meta) {
    // Seteando valores de la respuesta
    titulo_input.setText(meta.getTitulo());
    descripcion_input.setText(meta.getDescripcion());
    fecha_text.setText(meta.getFechaLim());


    // Obteniendo acceso a los array de strings para categorias y prioridades
    String[] categorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.entradas_categoria);
    String[] prioridades = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.entradas_prioridad);

    // Obteniendo la posición del spinner categorias
    int posicion_categoria = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++) {
        if (categorias[i].compareTo(meta.getCategoria()) == 0) {
            posicion_categoria = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Setear selección del Spinner de categorías
    categoria_spinner.setSelection(posicion_categoria);

    // Obteniendo la posición del spinner de prioridades
    int posicion_prioridad = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < prioridades.length; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "posición:" + i);
        if (prioridades[i].compareTo(meta.getPrioridad()) == 0) {
            posicion_prioridad = i;

            break;
        }
    }

    // Setear selección del Spinner de prioridades
    prioridad_spinner.setSelection(posicion_prioridad);
}

/**
 * Compara los datos actuales con aquellos que se obtuvieron
 * por primera vez en la respuesta HTTP
 *
 * @return true si los datos no han cambiado, de lo contrario false
 */
public boolean validarCambios() {
    return metaOriginal.compararCon(obtenederDatos());
}

/**
 * Retorna en una nueva meta creada a partir
 * de los datos del formulario actual
 *
 * @return Instancia {@link Meta}
 */
private Meta obtenederDatos() {

    String titulo = titulo_input.getText().toString();
    String descripcion = descripcion_input.getText().toString();
    String fecha = fecha_text.getText().toString();
    String categoria = (String) categoria_spinner.getSelectedItem();
    String prioridad = (String) prioridad_spinner.getSelectedItem();

    return new Meta("0", titulo, descripcion, fecha, categoria, prioridad);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Contribución a la AB
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:// CONFIRMAR
            if (!validarCambios())
                guardarMeta();
            else
                // Terminar actividad, ya que no hay cambios
                getActivity().finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_delete:// ELIMINAR
            mostrarDialogo(R.string.dialog_delete_msg);
            break;

        case R.id.action_discard:// DESCARTAR
            if (!validarCambios()) {
                mostrarDialogo(R.string.dialog_discard_msg);
            } else
                // Terminar actividad, ya que no hay cambios
                getActivity().finish();
            break;

    }
    ;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Guarda los cambios de una meta editada.
 * <p>
 * Si está en modo inserción, entonces crea una nueva
 * meta en la base de datos
 */
private void guardarMeta() {

    // Obtener valores actuales de los controles
    final String titulo = titulo_input.getText().toString();
    final String descripcion = descripcion_input.getText().toString();
    final String fecha = fecha_text.getText().toString();
    final String categoria = categoria_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String prioridad = prioridad_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

    map.put("idMeta", idMeta);
    map.put("titulo", titulo);
    map.put("descripcion", descripcion);
    map.put("fechaLim", fecha);
    map.put("categoria", categoria);
    map.put("prioridad", prioridad);

    // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

    // Depurando objeto Json...
    Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());

    // Actualizar datos en el servidor
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    Constantes.UPDATE,
                    jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            procesarRespuestaActualizar(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );

}

/**
 * Procesa todos las tareas para eliminar
 * una meta en la aplicación. Este método solo se usa
 * en la edición
 */
public void eliminarMeta() {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// MAPEO

    map.put("idMeta", idMeta);// Identificador

    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);// Objeto Json

    // Eliminar datos en el servidor
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    Constantes.DELETE,
                    jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // Procesar la respuesta
                            procesarRespuestaEliminar(response);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );
}

/**
 * Procesa la respuesta de eliminación obtenida desde el sevidor
 */
private void procesarRespuestaEliminar(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de éxito
                getActivity().setResult(203);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;

            case "2":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de falla
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Procesa la respuesta de actualización obtenida desde el sevidor
 */
private void procesarRespuestaActualizar(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de éxito
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;

            case "2":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de falla
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Actualiza la fecha del campo {@link fecha_text}
 *
 * @param ano Año
 * @param mes Mes
 * @param dia Día
 */
public void actualizarFecha(int ano, int mes, int dia) {
    // Setear en el textview la fecha
    fecha_text.setText(ano + "-" + (mes + 1) + "-" + dia);
}

/**
 * Muestra un diálogo de confirmación, cuyo mensaje esta
 * basado en el parámetro identificador de Strings
 *
 * @param id Parámetro
 */
private void mostrarDialogo(int id) {
    DialogFragment dialogo = ConfirmDialogFragment.
            createInstance(
                    getResources().
                            getString(id));
    dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "ConfirmDialog");
}

}
```

Datepicker

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class DatePickerFragment2 extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

OnDateSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnDateSelectedListener {
    void onDateSelected(int year, int month, int day);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnDateSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " debe implementar OnDateSelectedListener");
    }
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int ano, int mes, int dia) {
    mCallback.onDateSelected(ano, mes, dia);
}
}
```

CODIGO FINAL:

Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator() {
                        int result;
                        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Meta objeto1, Meta objeto2) {

```
                        // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                        try {
                            result = f.parse(objeto2.fechaLim).compareTo(f.parse(objeto1.fechaLim));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return result;

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hola Ismael. ¿Qué parte de tu codigo se encarga de ordenar los views?  Has de investigar e intentarlo , y si tienes problemas explicar qué error te está dando junto a la informacion que puedas dar como logs. Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. un saludo

Comment: Es decir, no es un error sino que quiero ordenar los items del recyclerview por fecha

Comment: Una duda Ismael, por lo que pones en el código, ordenas los elementos por su idMeta y lo quieres ordenar por fecha, entonces... porque no haces lo mismo pero utilizando la fecha para realizar la comparación???

Comment: Una curiosidad...por que si `fechaLim` va a almacenar un fecha, es de tipo String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente el problema es que estas intentando ordenar por fecha pero estas utilizando Strings. Intenta primero parsear los strings para poder compararles correctamente, prueba esta solucion:

```
Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator<Meta>() {
                DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                @Override
                public int compare(meta objeto1, meta objeto2) {

                    // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                    result = f.parse(objeto2.fechaLim).compareTo(f.parse(objeto1.fechaLim));
                    return result;

                }
            });
```

Comment: Gracias funciono!!!!! pongo el codigo para mas gente